# Speeding up function minimisation using Scipy's Powell method

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, least-squares

I am trying to solve a nonlinear least squares problem using Scipy's minimize-function in Python. The model is very complicated and (typically) depends on 14 parameters. Thus, I and many symbolic calculators are unable to write down any analytical expressions for the gradient of the objective function (the sum of squared residuals). However, based on visualisation, it would seem that the objective function is not differentiable at the minimum. Moreover, I tried `scipy.optimize.minimize` with some gradient-based methods, and the method is unable to locate the solution.

I have tried to visualise the objective function with respect to two variables while others are kept fixed. It seems that the objective function behaves as (almost) constant outside a very small region. This could explain why most (gradient-based) methods get stuck and the initial guess would need to be very close to the exact solution. Furthermore, I have noticed that the objective function takes very small (< 10^(-5)) values due to the model and data values being very small. Gradient-based methods might terminate when the objective function value is around 10^(-7) while the accurate solution would give around 10^(-10).

Luckily, Powell's method seems to be able to find the solution. For my purposes, however, the method is taking far too long to find the optimum; around 5-10 minutes. I noticed that the time could be reduced by taking less data points, thus making the objective function evaluations more efficient. However, the choice of the data points seems to be crucial to ensure that the method finds the correct solution. Now the method takes around 3 minutes; my objective is to accomplish the optimization in less than a minute. Evaluating the objective function takes 0.07 seconds.

The objective function is defined as:

```
def objective(*parameters):
    return np.linalg.norm(data - model(xs_data, *parameters), ord = 2, axis = 0)**2
```

Here's my line for the minimisation:

```
 minimize(lambda variables: objective(*variables), initial_guess, method='Powell', bounds = bounds, options={'xtol': 5e-4, 'ftol': 5e-4})
```

The results are:

```
 message: Optimization terminated successfully.
 success: True
 status: 0
 fun: 1.79714781920377e-11
 x: [ 3.537e+00  1.661e-01 ... -1.006e+01  4.037e-01]
 nit: 14
 direc: [[ 3.781e-01  4.889e-02 ...  3.919e-05  1.229e-02]
       [ 0.000e+00  1.000e+00 ...  0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
       ...
       [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00 ...  1.000e+00  0.000e+00]
       [-5.545e-03 -8.207e-04 ...  1.473e-05  4.853e-03]]
 nfev: 2469
```

I hope that someone could give me hints on how to accomplish the desired execution time. I wonder if the search in Powell's method could be parallelised somehow, or if I could apply some kind of a transformation to the data/objective function to efficiently find the minimum.

Here's a minimal reproducible example, where the model, however, does not capture the same characteristics (complexity, non-differentiabiility, lengthy computation time for the optimisation, very small values) as in my original problem. Nevertheless, I hope that this demonstrates how everything is defined:

The model could be defined as

```
def model(x, *parameters):
# Initialise:
result = 0

for i in range(len(parameters)):
    result += np.exp(-(x-parameters[i])**2)/(parameters[i]**2 + 1)

return result
```

Data comes from the model for x arguments

```
xs = np.linspace(-10, 20, 100)
```

and is given by

```
data = model(xs, *[0.5, 3, 10, 11])
```

The task is to estimate the parameters [0.5, 3, 10, 11] from the data using least squares method. The objective function is defined as

```
def objective(*params):
   return np.linalg.norm(data - model(xs, *params), ord = 2, axis = 0)**2
```

We require that the first parameter is between 0 and 1:

```
bounds = [(None, None) for i in range(4)]
bounds[0] = (0, 1)
```

The initial guess could be:

```
initial_guess = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: It would help if you included a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's still not a minimal reproducible example, what's ```data```, ```model```, ```xs_data```, ```parameters```, ```initial_guess``` and ```bounds```?

Comment: @Nin17 I added an example.

Comment: Ok but that whole code ran in 5.78 ms  on my machine and converged with only 155 function evaluations, are these realistic values?

Comment: No they are not. Unfortunately, I am unable to provide a minimal example that has the same characteristics as the original problem, and I am not comfortable with sharing the original (very long) code. Instead, I was hoping to get some general suggestions on how to reduce the computation time by e.g. parallelisation, using GPU somehow, transforming data, etc. I tried to describe the challenges of the optimisation problem.

Comment: well you can start by vectorizing the model function: ```def model(x, parameters):
    return (np.exp(-(x[:, None]-parameters[None])**2)/(parameters[None]**2 + 1)).sum(axis=1)```  and then using it as ```minimize(objective ...``` is already 15% faster

Comment: have you tried using [scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html)?

Comment: I had not, but I tried now. It could not find the correct solution.

Comment: are you giving an appropriate initial guess?

Comment: With gradient-based methods, the initial guess has to be very close to the optimum. For example, if I rounded the initial guess to the closest integer, the method does not converge towards an optimal solution. As I described, the objective function is almost constant and interesting things happen in a very very small area around the minimum. So far only Powell's method, which does not use gradients, has been able to find the optimal solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255291/discussion-between-nin17-and-mathslover).